# Onclick Image button - Logic not making sense

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

I'm having a very confusing time with this very simple onClick function in Javascript/html. I know there are many questions on this but couldn't quite find an answer given what my script does (Or doesn't in this case). It should be simple but for some reason the logic is just not working as I expect it too.

```
<h1>The onclick Event</h1>
<img id="onoff" onclick="changeImage();" src="images/Off Button.jpg" width="245" height="238">

<p>Click on button to turn "on"</p>

<script>
    function changeImage() {
        var image = document.getElementById("onoff");
        if (image.src.match("Off Button.jpg")){
            image.src = "images/On Button.jpg";
        }
        else{
            image.src="images/Off Button.jpg";
        }
    }
</script>
```

So as you can see this should take the original "off button" image and swap it to "on button" when it is clicked provided it is showing the "Off Button.jpg".

However, it does nothing, using the Chrome developer tools I can see the script doesn't even fire. But when I make these changes:

```
    if (image.src.match("Off Button.jpg")){
        image.src = "images/Off Button.jpg";
    }
    else{
        image.src="images/On Button.jpg";
```

It now fires and changes the Button to "On Button" but does not fire again to change it back. For me, this makes no sense logically but I might just be missing something really obvious. I know this is pretty basic but any help or explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: `match` expects regular expressions. You mean `includes`. Spaces are converted to `%20` in URLs, and the `src` _property_ is a URL. The `src` property is _not_ the same as the `src` _attribute_, i.e. `img.getAttribute("src")`. Why not simply log `img.src` to see what it contains?

Comment: Here's a less error-prone way of handling app state: https://jsfiddle.net/sguyfj7m/

Comment: Hi there, I wasn't aware that spaces are read differently like that. I changed the name of the source image names and script to "on"/"off" and the whole script now works as expected. Thank you @user4642212 for clarifying.

Out curiosity should you never put spaces in src file names when working with JavaScript or how does that work on such large scale websites?

Comment: See [Difference between object.src and object.getAttribute('src')](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19737143/4642212). Of course you _can_ work with spaces in file names. You just need to be aware of the differences between properties and attributes.

Comment: Oh thanks for that link makes a lot more sense now. I see what is at work in my script much better now. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I did some changes to the code and now it's working.
I used the relative path with `./` to img src and mostly you should avoid use spaces to name images or anything else - spaces always cause problems ;)

```
<h1>The onclick Event</h1>
<!-- relative path and no space in name on src -->
<img
    id="onoff"
    onclick="changeImage();"
    src="./images/off-button.jpg" 
    width="245"
    height="238"
/>

<p>Click on button to turn "on"</p>

<script>
    function changeImage() {
        var image = document.getElementById('onoff');
        if (image.src.match('off-button.jpg')) { /*  no space in name */
            image.src = './images/on-button.jpg'; /* relative path and no space 
            in name */
        } else {
            image.src = './images/off-button.jpg'; /* relative path and no space 
            in name */
        }
    }
</script>
```

Note - Remember to rename the images inside the images folder as well